# Prefer faster hosts over slower ones in Univa Grid Engine when scheduling jobs?

Tags: grid, cluster-computing, scheduling

I've got a cluster running Univa Grid Engine, with about fifteen compute nodes in a queue.  Five of the nodes are a fair bit slower than the other ten, just due to being older.

It's rare for our cluster to be fully utilized, so it's pretty common that there are slots free in the queue.  Right now, when jobs are submitted to an empty or under-utilized queue, they seem to pick nodes at random to run in.  Is it possible to configure the cluster so that it will let the faster nodes fill up before running jobs in the slower ones?  Thanks in advance!